# How to extract/delete old files from a tarball which has been updated

Tags: command-line, tar, archive

I've got a `tarball` named `test.tar` which I first created it by running:

```
echo start > 1
tar -cf test.tar 1
```

And then updated it by:

```
echo end > 1
tar -uf test.tar 1
```

Now if I get a list of files within this tar archive:

```
$ tar -tx test.tar
```

It gives me:

```
1
1
```

If I try to see what's in these files:

```
$ tar -xOf test.tar

start
end
```

And finally when I want to extract it:

```
$ tar -xf test.tar 1
$ cat 1
end
```

Is there anyway to extract the old version of `1`? (the one which contains `start`).

Another thing is deleting these files, when I use `--delete` parameter it'll delete all files with that name from archive. How can I only delete the old or new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC66):

> `--occurrence[=number]`
>
> This option can be used in conjunction with one of the subcommands >`--delete`, `--diff`, `--extract` or `--list` when a list of files is given >either on the command line or via `-T` option.
>
> This option instructs tar to process only the numberth occurrence of > each named file. Number defaults to 1, so
>
> `tar -x -f archive.tar --occurrence filename`
>
> will extract the first occurrence of the member `filename' from >`archive.tar' and will terminate without scanning to the end of the archive.

So, in your case to extract old version use:

```
tar -xf test.tar --occurrence=1 1
```

And for deletion run:

```
tar --delete -f test.tar --occurrence=1 1
```

---

Another workaround to extract both version is to simply use `--backup` switch:

```
tar -xf test.tar --backup
```

It will extract your files like:

```
1
1~
```

Which `1~` is the old one. If you got more than of two version use `--occurrence` switch instead.

You can also use `-w` to use `tar` interactive mode:

```
tar -xf test.tar -w
```

This time `tar` asks you for each action, you can choose the first version or last version to be extract by `y/n`.